# Remove base from the custom post type URL

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, functions, url-rewriting, urls

I wanted to add `blog` before the post slug in the URL.

The URL for the post type page was:

```
   http://example.com/blog/post-one
```

So basically to add `blog` before the posts url in **Settings >> permalink** I have selected *Custom structure* and the value  `/blog/%postname%/`

As I have entered the base in permalink structure it adds `blog` base to custom post type URLs as well.

There are too many custom post types. it shows this base before all urls.

Custom post type url:   `http://example.com/blog/news/post-name`

while it should be  `http://example.com/news/post_name`

custom post type url should be  without the base i added in custom permalink for default post type.

What's the solution of it.?  How can i  fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Add this on your register post type function:

```
'rewrite'         => array(
      'slug'      => 'news',
      'with_front'  => false
    ),
```

The "with_front => false" will remove the "blog" from the path.

Hope that it helps,
Cheers